# Android ProgressDialog runtime exception error

Tags: android, progressdialog, runtimeexception

I'm having trouble trying to put a ProgressDialog into my app. In my GameEngine class (which doesn't extend anything), I have the code shown below. The first line produces a runtime exception, and although I came across this thread that seems to be about the same error: [Android TimerTask throws RuntimeException if Show ProgressDialog is added in run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573711/android-timertask-throws-runtimeexception-if-show-progressdialog-is-added-in-run), I don't really understand how to implement the solution. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
    //Create ProgressDialog
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", 
            "Loading...", true);

    //Set Clusters before level starts
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        updateBacteria();
        updateAttraction();
        checkCollisions();
        moveObjectsAwayFromWalls();
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this method is not running in your Main Activity thread, you should change it. how? Set a Handler in the main activity and pass it to the thread (above). In the [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) you should implement the GUI related part of your method (i.e. `ProgressDialog`). When you need to show the `ProgressDialog`, just call your `Handler` and than keep processing (your loop in this case). Same for the `dismiss()`.

Comment: Bit more work than I was hoping for but it works, thanks.. Quick question though: Would I have to use a Handler if I wanted to use a Toast instead of a ProgressDialog to show my "loading.." text?

Answer (score 2):

You can only show dialogs in the UI thread (which is your main class which extends Activity). To be able to do this, you can write a `Handler` and use it to send messages from the non UI thread to the UI thread. Android have an example of this [in their ProgressDialog example.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog) View the snippet of code they have under "Example ProgressDialog with a second thread".

You can also follow the same method as written in the answer of the link you provided, although a Handler is a more robust approach.

Comment: Bit more work than I was hoping for but it works, thanks.. Quick question though: Would I have to use a Handler if I wanted to use a Toast instead of a ProgressDialog to show my "loading.." text?